# Calling Different Divs in Popup

Tags: javascript, html, video, popup, gallery

I am working with a 3 image gallery. When you click on the images a popup appears with an iframe inside. Currently the 3 different images when clicked all show the same video in the popup. I am wondering how to call the different videos for the different images. Also, is it possible to automatically start the video so you do not have to press play when the popup appears? Thank you guys my code is as follows.

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.login-window').click(function() {

            //Getting the variable's value from a link 
    var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');

    //Fade in the Popup
    $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);

    //Set the center alignment padding + border see css style
    var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
    var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2; 

    $(loginBox).css({ 
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });

    // Add the mask to body
    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

    return false;
});

    // When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
    $('a.close, #mask').live('click', function() { 
     $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
      $('#mask').remove();  
  }); 
 return false;
 });
});
</script>


      <div id="videos">
        <div id="header_start">
        <a class="login-window" href="#login-box"><img src="/images/video_holder1.jpg" style="padding-right: 20px; width: 316px; height: 186px;" /></a></div>
            <div class="login-popup" id="login-box">
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="foo.com" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <a class="close" href="#"><img alt="Close" class="btn_close" src="close_pop.png" title="Close Window" /></a>
                </div></div>
      <div id="videos1">
        <div id="header_start">
        <a class="login-window" href="#login-box"><img src="/images/video_holder2.jpg" style="padding-right: 20px; width: 316px; height: 186px;" /></a></div>
            <div class="login-popup" id="login-box">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="foo.com" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <a class="close" href="#"><img alt="Close" class="btn_close" src="close_pop.png" title="Close Window" /></a>
            </div></div>
       <div id="videos2">     
         <div id="header_start">
         <a class="login-window" href="#login-box"><img src="/images/video_holder3.jpg" style="padding-right: 20px; width: 316px; height: 186px;" /></a></div>
            <div class="login-popup" id="login-box">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="foo.com" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <a class="close" href="#"><img alt="Close" class="btn_close" src="close_pop.png" title="Close Window" /></a>
            </div></div>
```

Comment: You have 3 divs with the same id (login-box), so when you do `$(loginBox).fadeIn()` this will have effect on all the 3 divs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When I change the id="login-box" on each video nothing appears in the popup. I am not sure how to call the different id's in the script without rewriting new script for each one.

Comment: Try with this: `$(this).next('#login-box').fadeIn(300);` for the fadeIn.

Comment: Not sure what I am doing wrong but I still get nothing in the popup now. I changed the id's to the following id="1loggin-box", id="2login-box, id="3login-box". I used the code you mentioned above in the script. Any other pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: If you have changed the ids it wont work anymore. Keep the ids different (ALWAYS) and try this: `$(this).next('.login-popup').fadeIn(300);`

Comment: Nothing is opening in the popup again when I replace the `$(loginBox).fadeIn(300);` with  `$(this).next('.login-popup').fadeIn(300);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Dim13i/tnGRZ/4/)**

There were some mistakes in your jQuery code, I've made some changes. When you click on an image you can access to the correct `.login-popup` like this:

```
var $loginBox = $(this).parent().next('.login-popup');
```

Try to get "inspired" and make the modifications you need to get exactly what you want.

It is also important you keep in mind that IDs should be unique in your code. Use classes if you want to give the same properties and style to multiples elements.

Comment: Thank you Dim13i!The fiddle works great and allowed me to customize a bit for my needs. I really appreciate it!

Comment: I have one more question for you. Is it possible to kill the action (video playing) when the popup is closed. This would be great so the video isn't continuously playing while the others are trying to be viewed.

Comment: What kind of video will you include? (Youtube, etc...)

Comment: A separate Youtube video for each one.

Comment: Ok, I didn't do anything special, but you can try here: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Dim13i/tnGRZ/8/). The video is launched automatically and when you click on the close icon the video stops with the fadeOut.

Comment: The fadeOut isn't currently pausing the video.

Comment: You want to pause it or stop it?

Comment: Stop it, I'm sorry it's been a long day.

Comment: Well, in the previous fiddle I posted the video stops once you click on the close button.

Comment: When I go to the previous [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dim13i/tnGRZ/8/) the video continues once it is closed.

Comment: Maybe you linked the wrong fiddle? Yes, that is the same one I am viewing.

Comment: Anyway normally you can do whatever you want with this: [LINK](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#GettingStarted).

Comment: I was digging into to that a bit when I saw your Fenway video link thru googleapis.com. Thanks again for all your help, I really appreciate it. This community is always a great help and full of endless resources.